# iOS: Draw MKCircle with a fixed radius in MKMapView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkoverlay

Currently my MKCircle grows in size as I zoom into the map and shrinks as I zoom out. Is there anyway to draw a MKCircle of fixed radius regardless of zoom level? I'm thinking of overriding

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

and remove the circle, then create a new one with a new radius and add it back to the overlay, but it seems a little inefficient. Anyone know of a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using a custom MKAnnotationView that shows a circle? That will maintain size as you zoom around.

Comment: Is MKAnnotation the little red pin? It's just I expect its position to constantly change over time as to represent the location of a moving person on the map instead of pinned to a specific location. Is it possible to just draw the red ball? I don't know too much about MKAnnotation... Thanks!

Comment: MKAnnotationView is the visible part of the MKAnnotation, yes. You can subclass MKAnnotationView to make it look like whatever you want, and you can cause it to move over time by changing the coordinate property on the MKAnnotation.

Comment: Thank you Jesse! I will look into MKAnnotationView.